# Пропорциональное растягивание картинок?

Tags: html, javascript, css

Расскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает, как растягивать картинку пропорционально, чтобы она не была сплющена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

увеличивать/уменьшать одно из измерений, либо высоту либо ширину, а другое не указывать вовсе.

Comment: Есть еще малоизвестный, но вообще-то интуитивный способ - `style="width: NNpx; height: auto;"`

Comment: @Sh4dow да, есть, спасибо за уточнение.

Comment: @FLK, @Sh4dow, спасибо, сам когда мне надо было не догадался до этого... в фото*опе изменял размер картинки)))

Answer (score 0):

Если скриптом, то вот у нас есть исходное изображение и мы знаем его размеры. Делим высоту на длину или наоборот. Мы получили коэффициент отношения. Затем изменяем одну из сторон и используем её и коэффициент для другой стороны. Пример:

`233x411
К:0.57 (высота к длине, т.е. высота=0.57*длина)
Изменяем длину = 500, то длина будет = 0.57 **500 = 285`